# how to extract cluster data from rds file in R

Tags: r

I have read RDS file, where the data is stored after running PCA and UMAP. I got various clusters in it. However, I only want 2 of the cluster data, as to which cells belong to those groups.

I used `sce_3_1_1_after_5000_23@meta.data$seurat_clusters` to get cluster.

Is there a function to subset specific cluster data? please suggest

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plz use `dput()` to obtain reproducible example.
I think you could use `filter` of dplyr package to select rows belonging to wanted clusters :

```
filter(your_dataset, class_column == "cluster_1" & class_column == "cluster_2")
```

Here I supposed that your dataset contains a column `class_column` that represents the cluster label of  observations.